# Integral over Laguerre Polynomials

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I would like to solve Integrals of the type

$\int_0^{\infty}dx e^{-x}x^{m+2}L^m_k(x)L^m_{k+j}(x)$,

for $m,k,j$ integers (and $m,k\geq0$).

On this page I found an expression which should do the job: http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LaguerreL3/21/02/01/, in particular, there is the formula

[image].

However, I have difficulties evaluating this expression because for $\alpha\geq1+\beta$ (in my example: $\alpha=m+3$ and $\beta=m$) the Gamma function in the denominator is divergent. In fact I am not even able to reproduce the usual orthogonality relation

[image].

Trying to evaluate the Integrals using

```
Integrate[Exp[-x]x^(m+2)LaguerreL[k,m,x]LaguerreL[k+j,m,x],{x,0,Infinity}]
```

did not work either (Mathematica 11 returns the input identically).

Is there a way to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid parameter confusion I renamed m->mm and n->nn in the Wolfram Expression.

```
Integrate[(t^(-1 + \[Alpha])*LaguerreL[mm, \[Lambda], p*t]*
 LaguerreL[nn, \[Beta], p*t])/E^(p*t), {t, 0, Infinity}] == 
(Gamma[\[Alpha]]*Gamma[1 + nn - \[Alpha] + \[Beta]]*
 Gamma[1 + mm + \[Lambda]]*
 HypergeometricPFQ[{-mm, \[Alpha], \[Alpha] - \[Beta]}, {-nn + \
 \[Alpha] - \[Beta], 1 + \[Lambda]}, 1])/p^\[Alpha]/
 (mm!*nn!*Gamma[1 - \[Alpha] + \[Beta]]*Gamma[1 + \[Lambda]])
```

Then you get to your integrand with the following substitutions:

```
(t^(-1 + \[Alpha])*LaguerreL[mm, \[Lambda], p*t]*
LaguerreL[nn, \[Beta], p*t])/E^(p*t) /. 
{t->x,p -> 1, mm -> k,nn -> k + j, \[Alpha] -> m + 3, \[Lambda] -> m, \[Beta] -> m}
(* (x^(2 + m)*LaguerreL[k, m, x]*LaguerreL[j + k, m, x])/E^x  *)
```

Do the same substitutions to the Wolfram result:

```
(Gamma[\[Alpha]]*Gamma[1 + nn - \[Alpha] + \[Beta]]*
 Gamma[1 + mm + \[Lambda]]*
 HypergeometricPFQ[{-mm, \[Alpha], \[Alpha] - \[Beta]}, {-nn + \
 \[Alpha] - \[Beta], 1 + \[Lambda]}, 1])/p^\[Alpha]/
 (mm!*nn!*Gamma[1 - \[Alpha] + \[Beta]]*Gamma[1 + \[Lambda]]) /. 
 {t->x,p -> 1, mm -> k,nn -> k + j, \[Alpha] -> m + 3, \[Lambda] -> m, \[Beta] -> m+10^-7}
```

The trick here is to add a little offset to the parameter beta that avoids both the hypergeo function in the nominator and the gamma function in the denominator getting infinite values at the same time. Now you numerically integrate your expression after giving values to the still free parameters like:

```
m = 2; k = 3;j = -1;
NIntegrate[(x^(2 + m)*LaguerreL[k, m, x]*LaguerreL[j + k, m, x])/E^x, {x, 0, Infinity}]
(* -960. *)
```

and can compare with the output of the Wolfram result given above.